# global immutable HashMap in Rust

Tags: rust

How to create a global immutable HashMap in Rust?

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub const ID_INDEX_MAPPER: HashMap<u16, u16> = [
    (13287, 0),
    (2387, 1),
    (5873, 2),
].iter().cloned().collect();

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0015]: cannot call non-const fn `core::slice::<impl [(u16, u16)]>::iter` in constants
 --> src/lib.rs:7:3
  |
7 | ].iter().cloned().collect();
  |   ^^^^^^
  |
  = note: calls in constants are limited to constant functions, tuple structs and tuple variants
```

Comment: [`OnceLock`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.OnceLock.html), [`once_cell::Lazy`](https://docs.rs/once_cell/latest/once_cell/sync/struct.Lazy.html), or [`lazy_static`](https://docs.rs/lazy_static/latest/lazy_static/) can be used to initialise runtime data once lazily.